# Is it possible to convert/copy/transfer my MULTISIM circuit into LTspice file?

Tags: oscillator, ltspice, digital-communications, multisim, amplitude-modulation

[image]

Hello,
By any chance, if is there a way to convert/copy/transfer my MULTISIM circuit into LTspice.

Would appreciate a lot your responses
Thank you

Comment: Search for LTSpice import/export, I'm sure you'll find it isn't worth the effort.  Especially with such a simple schematic.  You could have it redrawn in 20 minutes or less.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron on this: by the time you would have waited for someone to respond, you could have redrawn that, simulate it, print it, etc. If your schematic is more involved, the way the graphical schematics are saved will, no doubt, differ, so you'd only be relying on the raw SPICE netlist, which is awful to recreate in a GUI, so you're back to square one. In short: if a search doesn't reveal a MULTISIM to LTspice exporter, better start the manual work. Even LTspice's own export deals with netlists.